# Angular Material UI InjectionToken MAT_TAB_GROUP error

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to tab with Angular Material UI. I prepared 2 components.
First component;

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="0">
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Second component;

```
<mat-tab [label]="label" [disabled]="disabled">
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-tab>
```

When I start the system I get the following error.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken MAT_TAB_GROUP -> InjectionToken MAT_TAB_GROUP -> InjectionToken MAT_TAB_GROUP]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MAT_TAB_GROUP!
> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken MAT_TAB_GROUP -> InjectionToken MAT_TAB_GROUP -> InjectionToken MAT_TAB_GROUP]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MAT_TAB_GROUP!

What is the reason? How can I solve it?

Comment: Import "MatTabsModule" in your appModule. `import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
`

Comment: I added it before

Answer (score 1):

You have mat-tab-group in one component, and mat-tab in second.
Mat-tab has to be surrounded by mat-tab-group. But it does not happen.
Because your structure in HTML is:

```
mat-tab-group
  your-custom-component
    mat-tab-1
    mat-tab-2
```

While it should be :

```
mat-tab-group
  your-custom-component
    mat-tab-1
    mat-tab-2
```

You can fix it by having mat-tab-group and mat-tab inside the same component.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks. I have wrapped my custom-comp. inside <mat-tab-group></mat-tab-group>